# DAX: Calculation for clearing overdues from oldest

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Let's assume that a CLIENT was issued some invoices over time. Amounts from those invoices are cumulated in the report in some groups like 0 days, 1-30 days, 31-60 days, 61-120 days, >120 days depending on their payment terms. Now the client has paid X amount of money to cover part or whole of his balance.

I'm looking for calculation to clear the balance with the amount the client has paid starting from the oldest invoices.

Data is stored in a table loaded from SAP. I have just the fields with Client details, his account balance by periods in key-value pairs and indicator if it's credit or debit

[CLIENT] [Period] [Amount] [Credit/Debit]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've managed to solve it and here's how:

I've created a table with aging periods and since part of them were overlapping like (1-30 days and 1-5 days, 6-16 days, etc.) I've added two columns to sort and exclude overlapping periods: [order 1] and [order 2].

[image: Final table view]

then I've created a measure "Account balance clearing" which consists of:

Variable to calculate total debit in whole date range:

```
VAR Debit = CALCULATE(
        SUM( 'AR Ageing Analysis'[Value] ),
        'AR Ageing Analysis'[Debit/Credit Indicator.Debit/Credit Indicator Level 01] = "H",
        FILTER(
            ALL( 'Aging periods' ),
            NOT( ISBLANK( 'Aging periods'[order 1] ) )
        )
    )
```

The **CREDIT/DEBIT INDICATOR = "H"** is looking only for negative balance because in source data positive and negative balance is in the same table splitted by those periods and H is for negative and **"S"** is for positive.

Another variable is for calculating positive balance in currently selected period and older:

```
VAR Credit = CALCULATE(
        SUM( 'AR Ageing Analysis'[Value] ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( 'AR Ageing Analysis'[Attribute], 'AR Ageing Analysis'[Debit/Credit Indicator.Debit/Credit Indicator Level 01] ),
            'AR Ageing Analysis'[Debit/Credit Indicator.Debit/Credit Indicator Level 01] = "s"
        ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( 'Aging periods' ),
            'Aging periods'[order 1] <= SELECTEDVALUE( 'Aging periods'[order 1] ) &&
            NOT( ISBLANK( 'Aging periods'[order 1] ) )
        )
    )
```

Another one just tu sum them both:

```
VAR Balance = Credit + Debit
```

To finally return cleared balance in periods and proper Total:

```
RETURN 

IF(
    HASONEVALUE( 'Aging periods'[Value] ),
    IF( Balance < 0, 0, Balance ),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM( 'AR Ageing Analysis'[Value] ),
        FILTER(
            ALL( 'Aging periods' ),
            NOT( ISBLANK( 'Aging periods'[order 1] ) )
        )
    )
)
```